Translate rotated element relative to document
I'm trying to translate a rotated element but when I do so, the element translates considering the rotated axis. I'm trying to translate the element considering the axis pre rotation. How do I do that?
I've created a jsfiddle to illustrate the issue : https://jsfiddle.net/c03wpyuz/6/


$(document).ready(() => {

  var tx = 0;
  var ty = 0;
  var ag = 0;
  var el = $('#test');

  setTimeout(() => {
    ag = 45;
    el.css('transform', 'rotate(' + ag + 'deg)');
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(() => {
    tx = 100;
    ty = 0;
    el.css('transform', 'rotate(' + ag + 'deg) translate3d(' + tx + 'px, ' + ty + 'px, 0)');
  }, 2000);

});
#test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: center;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
</div>



The element will rotate after 1 second then after 2 seconds it will translate. The issue is that I'm only translating it over the X axis but the axis is then rotated.

Sounds like you simply want to change the order - 'translate3d(...) rotate(...)' ...?

Try putting translate3d before rotate:


$(document).ready(() => {

  var tx = 0;
  var ty = 0;
  var ag = 0;
  var el = $('#test');

  setTimeout(() => {
       ag = 45;
       el.css('transform', 'rotate('+ag+'deg)');
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(() => {
       tx = 100;
       ty = 0;
       el.css('transform', 'translate3d('+tx+'px, '+ty+'px, 0) rotate('+ag+'deg)');
  }, 2000);


});
#test{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: center;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">

</div>



Another approach is to use translate and rotate separately, instead of transform (but be aware of their coverage):


$(document).ready(() => {
  var tx = 0;
  var ty = 0;
  var ag = 0;
  var el = $('#test');

  setTimeout(() => {
       ag = 45;
       el.css('rotate', `${ag}deg`);
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(() => {
       tx = 100;
       ty = 0;
       el.css('translate', `${tx}px ${ty}px 0px`);
  }, 2000);
});
#test{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: center;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">

</div>




Dang... Didn't know that had an influence over the result. Thanks, will validate soon.
